# How do I get the d3 svg points to stay in their correct position on the leaflet map when zooming?

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

```
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([10.0, 15.0], 2);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FidW1hZm9vIiwiYSI6ImNqMWE3cnlqcTA5dncyd216YjI0bnY4dGEifQ.fgmXgmkvialdBd3D405_BA', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
maxZoom: 18,
id: 'mapbox.streets',
accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FidW1hZm9vIiwiYSI6ImNqMWE3cnlqcTA5dncyd216YjI0bnY4dGEifQ.fgmXgmkvialdBd3D405_BA'
}).addTo(map);

L.svg().addTo(map);

var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).select('svg');

var g = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'leaflet-zoom-hide');

const URL = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&limit=200'

function getEarthquakeData() {
  fetch(URL)
  .then((results) => {
return results.json();
  })
  .then((result) => {

function projectPoint(x,y) {
  var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y,x));
  this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
}

var transform = d3.geoTransform({point: projectPoint}),
path = d3.geoPath().projection(transform);

function applyLatLngToLayer(d){
  var y = d.geometry.coordinates[1];
  var x = d.geometry.coordinates[0];
  return map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y,x));
}

// console.log(result.features);
// result.features.forEach(function(d) {
//   d.LatLng = new L.LatLng(d.geometry.coordinates[1],
//     d.geometry.coordinates[0])
//   });

var circle = g.selectAll('circle')
.data(result.features)
.enter().append('circle')
.style('fill','darkred')
.attr('r', 2)
.attr('opacity',0.5);

function update() {

  circle.attr("transform",
  function(d) {
    return "translate("+
    applyLatLngToLayer(d).x+","+
    applyLatLngToLayer(d).y+")";
  });

  var bounds = path.bounds(result),
  topLeft = bounds[0],
  bottomRight = bounds[1];

  svg.attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
    .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
    .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
    .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");

  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")");

  }

  map.on('viewreset', update);
  update();

  })

}


getEarthquakeData();
```

The above code will add points to a leaflet map once it fetches the data I'm interested in mapping.  The problem is that when I zoom in on the map all of the points remain in their same position while the map background changes view.  The points are not actually "affixed" to the correct location in any view besides the opening view.  I know this has something to do with the way I'm updating the view but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Please help!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are using version 1.*, if so then this is a known issue:

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5016

Switch from the `viewreset` event to the `moveend` event and you should be ok.